# Does 14.10 know to disable integrated graphics if I have discrete graphics?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, integrated

Just trying to figure some stuff out and fiddling around with some settings to maximize smoothness and framerate in games and stuff. So my question is in the title; I ask this because when I run lspci and other commands I can still see my i7 processor's integrated graphics in the output commands as well as my nvidia GTX 660. I even put the drivers for the intel graphics in my blacklist, but it still is showing up. Therefore, does my the kernel know to utilize the GTX over the intel (all third party drivers are up to date, am NOT using Noveau drivers but am using official nvidia).

Answer (score 1):

### Yes and no...

Ubuntu will *use* the discrete GPU if its module (a.k.a. "driver") is loaded, but it will *not disable* the integrated card.

### Why?

Some people use both cards at the same time: Integrated for simple windowing, GPU for gaming, video, ...

If you want to **turn off** the integrated graphics driver:

1. Go into your BIOS and look for graphics related options (every BIOS is different) and turn off the integrated graphics there.  Sometimes it's easy, but sometimes it's not obvious and you have to change the memory settings of the integrated graphics to '0'.  *Refer to your BIOS documentation*.
2. If BIOS settings don’t work, you can still blacklist the module itself, but the memory allocated to the card by the BIOS will still be unavailable to Ubuntu.  (you didn't provide any module information so if you don't know how to do this, *ask a new question*.)